# Intellisense user control for Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

Is there a text editor that can be used to create intellisense based projects (similar to Avalon Edit - but this is for WPF)? I am not looking for a simple auto complete. I am looking for something more like a code editor which can show suggestions while the user types.

Comment: I meant I need to create intellisense based project. So basically, I need to create something like a code editor.

Comment: I need controls that support intellisense. I am converting my WPF project to angular. In wpf, I used avalon edit ( http://avalonedit.net/ )

Comment: ok - I found something that may work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xD2ViRZnMY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) by Jetbrains is an excellent Web IDE for angular. However it is not lightweight, Webstorm requires ["1 GB RAM minimum, 2 GB RAM recommended , 1.5 GB hard disk space + at least 1 GB for caches 1024x768 minimum screen resolution"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/installing-and-launching.html)

[VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is also an excellent text editor and it is lightweight and powerful too.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) works very well with Angular projects. [Tutorial how to use it with Angular.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial)

Comment: I meant I need to create intellisense based project. So basically, I need to create something like a code editor.

Comment: One way to this is to build on [Atom editor](https://atom.io/) and write a package for it. Do you need to write whole project from scratch?

Comment: - yes I do have to build from scratch

Answer (score 0):

VS code with this extension should do the trick - [Angular v5 Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.Angular2)

Comment: I need controls that support intellisense. I am converting my WPF project to angular. In wpf, I used avalon edit ( http://avalonedit.net/ )

Comment: You might want to edit your question to indicate you are trying to create a text editor with intellisense capabilities. That does not seem to be clear currently.

Comment: The codebase for the extension I linked to might be a good place to look for implementation ideas -- https://github.com/johnpapa/vscode-angular-snippets